# Effect of outliers points on the stationarity of a time series

Tags: time-series

Do outliers points in a time series violate stationarity assumptions? and why?

Comment: Outliers can happen by accident.  That's why we use probability models to describe time series data!

Comment: Are any of the assumptions specifically about outliers? Welcome to CV!

Comment: so, is the answer yes or no?

Comment: As usual, *it depends.*  If you would like to provide details of the circumstances that prompted this question, then we might be able to be more definite.